# Excel nested if function returns false or true instead of a numerical value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my formula, I do not know what is wrong with it

=IF((E7+RANDBETWEEN(1,30))>$D$2,IF($D$2-RANDBETWEEN(1,30)>E7,$D$2-RANDBETWEEN(1,30)<E7,$D$2-RANDBETWEEN(1,30)),E7)

Comment: Hey. I think you need to specify the question a bit better... what are you trying to achieve? Expected result / actual result? Example of the data you use?

Answer (score 0):

Only the `$D$2-RANDBETWEEN(1,30)<E7` part will return a boolean result, if I assume all the source data cells contain numerical values.
Use the "Evaluate Formula" button provided by Excel to locate the exact place where it went rong.